# WordPress Ajax call very slow and jittery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been working on a website for some time now and while they do have a large amount of content and I have upgraded them, the AJAX load more call on the masonry grid is very slow. I have tried caching and using a CDN but it's still taking a very long time, particularly after the first instance.

Does anyone have any ideas? Website is `www.noctismag.com`

Here's the script I'm using to run it, in my footer.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        /* Masonry + Infinite Scroll */
        var $container = $('#grid-container');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.post'
            });
        });
        $('#grid-container').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.post'
            , columnWidth: 258
        });
        $container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector: '#page-nav'
            , nextSelector: '#page-nav a'
            , itemSelector: '.post'

        }, function (newElements) {
            var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
                opacity: 0
            });
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
                $newElems.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
                $container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
            });
        });
        $(window).unbind('.infscr');
        jQuery("#page-nav a").click(function () {
            jQuery('#grid-container').infinitescroll('retrieve');
            return false;
        });
        $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, opt) {
            if (xhr.status == 404) $('#page-nav a').remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does the Ajax request send back HTML code? 
If it's the case try  to change the code, Ajax call must return data as a JSON string and a front-end function will transform that data to render it on grid.

Comment: Hi Stev, here's the code i'm using to employ the Ajax:

Comment: Sorry, i'll add it above

Comment: I can't handle now i will check later in the afternoon 

Comment: I can't check it your website is "underconstruction" =)

Comment: - you don't have to answer if you cannot fully help. there is a comment section you can use for that.